# asp.net - maxlength not working

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a textbox as an input - markup below - this is a aspx page - see the markup below:

```
<input id="Number" runat="server" type="text" maxlength="6" />
```

However on screen - after I type in 6 digits or 6 letters it is allowing me to continiue typing?

Any ideas why?

Comment: Seems to be working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADZGE/) i tried in aspx too. its working though

Comment: Try using textbox instead of input with runat=server

Comment: Yeah - cant understand what the problem is - I can see it the maxLength="6" if I view page source as well????

Comment: Please add more information (browser used, etc.) Do you have any javascript which is directly affecting the input?

Comment: please create a fiddle! here : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: :/ - confused - suddenly started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="Number" runat="server" type="text" maxlength="6"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You can also add attribute pattern="[0-9]*", If you only want numbers in this field